# ¿Cómo activar el resultado del botón pulsado para poder pasar por parámetro el texto del botón a otro?

Tags: javascript, php

En una lista de botones, quiero obtener el texto de cada botón al pulsarlo, y pasar por parámetro el valor **clave** al archivo `Resultado.php`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches("#botonMarcajes")) {
      var clave = $("#botonMarcajes").text(); // este es el parametro que no me pasa..
      var fechaINI = $("#fecha1").val();
      var fechaFIN = $("#fecha2").val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "Resultado.php",
        data: "Fecha_INI=" + fechaINI + "&Fecha_FIN=" + fechaFIN + "&opc=añadir&clave=" + clave,
        type: "post",
        success: function ($datos) {
          $("#Marcajes").html($datos);
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Explica mejor cual es el problema y que es lo que quieres realizar, tal cual esta redactada tu pregunta es difícil comprender el problema, edita tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tenes que reemplazar esto:

```
var clave = $("#botonMarcajes").text();
```

Por esto:

```
var clave = $(e.target).text();
```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches("#botonMarcajes")) {

      var clave = $(e.target).text();
      console.log(clave)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="botonMarcajes">Boton 1</button>
<button type="button" id="botonMarcajes">Boton 2</button>
```

PD: No debería existir más de un elemento con `id="botonMarcajes"`. Se supone que los IDs deben ser únicos. Considera utilizar clases (*o algún otro atributo*) para agrupar elementos.

Referencia:

- [MDN Docs > HTML > Atributo id](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: Gracias por la Solucion :)) funciona bien.. me pasa el texto del boton como parametro.. al archivo . php .

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo con JS, ten en cuenta que si tienes un grupo de elementos lo mas factible es agruparlos mediante una `clase`, y con `id` se utiliza para elementos que deseas identificar como únicos.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var botones = document.querySelectorAll('.botonMarcajes');
  botones.forEach((boton) => {
    boton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      var boton = e.target;
      //console.log(boton)
      if (boton.matches(".botonMarcajes")) {

      var clave = boton.textContent; // este es el parámetro a enviar
      /*var fechaINI = document.getElementById('fecha1').value;
      var fechaFIN = document.getElementById('fecha2').value;*/
      console.log(clave)
      /*$.ajax({
        url: "Resultado.php",
        data: "Fecha_INI=" + fechaINI + "&Fecha_FIN=" + fechaFIN + "&opc=añadir&clave=" + clave,
        type: "post",
        success: function($datos) {
          $("#Marcajes").html($datos);
        }
      })*/

      }
    })
  });
})
```

```html
<button class='botonMarcajes'>boton1</button>
<button class='botonMarcajes'>boton2</button>
<button class='botonMarcajes'>boton3</button>
<button class='botonMarcajes'>boton4</button>
```

**NOTA**: No olvides descomentar el Ajax y las variables de fecha

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por el Aporte y la Solución. Vamos avanzando...